# Aegir stuck clone/migration/install tasks

Tags: mysql, drupal, aegir

I'm working on Aegir for migrating/cloning sites from platform1/db1 to platform2/db2. Platform1, platform2, db1 and db2 are verified successfully, but when i try to migrate/clone site the tasks spinning for ever. When i go into the server i can see the db is created on db2 and site is created on platform2 but the task is unfinished which is always in progress. I cancelled the task and re verified the platform which din't help.

Is there anything i'm missing or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to compare site creation times on both servers. It could take as long to migrate a site over as it does creating a site.

If that works (creating a site on db2) I would try and disable unstable/custom modules until it works. It sounds as though something is interfering.

(Btw in my opinion you shoud post at least the last lines of the task log, as well as how long you waited and how big the site's backups are, and any relevant info on the db engines etc. I notice you forgot to talk about installs on db2 too.)